# What exercises can help relieve outter arch strain?

Tags: sports, foot-pain

I have a basketball player that I am beginning to train.  He was doing distance running and strained his outer arch in one of his feet.  Looking for some recommendations on exercises or anything that he can do to help the issue.  He will continue to play basketball on this no matter what so "rest" isn't a good answer here.

Also he did this a couple of days ago and he said his foot felt better after playing for a bit but not 100% but then after he is in a lot of pain.

Comment: What is the main reason that "rest" is out of scope? If the injury is bad enough for not being able to go 100% and - most likely - the basketball season is over there shouldn't be that much pressure.

Comment: @FredrikD - He is trying to make a national team.  It is not my place to tell him to quit because of the pain.  I don't believe it to be a stress fracture so I don't see long-term issue.

Answer (score 1):

If he's playing at that level, getting an X-ray done shouldn't be an issue, and would be worth doing in the first instance, best to be sure.

Other than the normal advice of ice, and taking anti inflamatories.
If you have assess to a floatation belt, running in water is great, especially if used along with a heart rate monitor to keep the heart rate up.  It will really help to maintain fitness without stressing the injury.

Comment: Everyone has access to have x-rays done.  He could also have an MRI, full body scan, and any other test.  I understand all of my choices.  Was looking for help getting an athlete trying to make an elite national team on the court faster.  And yes he is afraid (and rightly so) that if he is perceived as injured he may not make the team.

Comment: Honesty is much better in this context, both in the short and long time fram. If the coaches cuts someone else from the team and it turns out that the injury is more serious -> not great for the relationships.